# Can't extract anything in 7z - Unknown error -2147024872 - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: extract, rar

I just can't extract any .rar or .zip or .7z file with 7z.
The program reads:

Scanning the drive for archives:

ERROR: No more files

Then the file's name.
And then:

System ERROR:
Error desconocido -2147024872

When I installed the program used:
"sudo apt install p7zip-full"

Research wasn't fruitful, the problems were not related to mine.

Help ;(
old laptop btw

Comment: What is the exact filename?